# SOAPUI: run Test Step with groovy without modifying the Test Step Body

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I'm new to SOAPUI and groovy so please advice if I'm doing any mistake in my approach.
I've a Test Step with a JSON body. This test step needs to have some additional JSON section based on some other parameters. Previously I was manually modifying the Test Step each time.
Now, I've created a groovy script that reads the Request from the Test step and appends the required section if needed.
I want to run the Test Step with the new JSON request generated through the Groovy Script.
Problem is I can not modify the original request in the Test Step since I'm reading it in the first place.

To give you an example:

Test Step as below request:

```
{ "services" : [{
    "city" : "paris",
    "phoneNo" : "1234567890",
    "actoin" : "add",
    "reason" : "generic"
    },
    {
    "city" : "london",
    "phoneNo" : "2234567890",
    "actoin" : "add",
    "reason" : "generic"
    }]
}
```

If I get a value `country = US` in some other Test Step then I 'll fetch the cities from that Test Step and modify my current Test Step as :

```
{ "services" : [{
    "city" : "paris",
    "phoneNo" : "1234567890",
    "actoin" : "add",
    "reason" : "generic"
    },
    {
    "city" : "london",
    "phoneNo" : "2234567890",
    "actoin" : "add",
    "reason" : "generic"
    },
    {"city" : "miami",
    "phoneNo" : "000000",
    "reason" : "promo"
    }]
}
```

I can think of two approaches:

1. Read the reqest each time and delete any additional section with `reason = "promo"`
2. Run the test step through groovy without changing Test step Request.
   But I don't how to implement these approaches.

Comment: Is the number of elements in "services" list fixed, i.e. 3? Your REST Request Test Step has 2 and based on the value from some other Test Step you intent to add another element to the list?

Comment: @VN'sCorner No, the size is variable. However, the size with reason=generic is fixed with 2. In the test step request, I’ve parameterised the city tag. So, paris and london are coming from a property file

Comment: Re "I want to run the Test Step with the new JSON request generated through the Groovy Script. Problem is I can not modify the original request in the Test Step since I'm reading it in the first place.".  Very often, my request step does not contain the actual payload.  You can use preceeding groovy step(s) that build your payload based on logic.  In the test step itself, you can use the {} syntax to pull payload from groovy scripts.

Comment: @ChrisAdams I suppose you are suggesting is to use ${groovyStep#result} in the Test step and return the paylod through groovy. But the problem is that groovy pay load is generated through the modified test step itself. So, the groovy script will now read ${groovyStep#result} instead of the payload

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I follow.  Bit difficult without some further details or screenshots of SoapUI.

Comment: @ChrisAdams Thanks for the suggestion. I had an incorrect understanding that whole request is modified with ${groovyScript#result}. I'm able to achieve the result with

{ "services" : [{
    "city" : "paris",
    "phoneNo" : "1234567890",
    "actoin" : "add",
    "reason" : "generic"
    },
    {
    "city" : "london",
    "phoneNo" : "2234567890",
    "actoin" : "add",
    "reason" : "generic"
    }
    ${groovyStep#result}
]
}